# Signed fully trusted form template in InfoPath 2010

Tags: infopath, certificate

I've create an InfoPath form template in InfoPath 2010. I need to sign it to make it full trusted, but when I click choose certificate in Form Options - Security, I get the following message:

> **No certificate available**
>
> No certificates meet the application crit...

I tried to put my code signing certificate in the Personal and in die Trusted Publishers store, but to no avail. Is something wrong with my certificate or did I just put it in the wrong store? Is there maybe a way to choose the certificate from an export file?

Comment: I think I found my problem: the certificate export I got from our CA ist without private key. I will get one including the private key and post if that helps ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MMC certificate snap-in, go to your certificate's properties and make sure your certificate is issued for "code signing".  I tried to import my server's certificate and discovered that it was only good for the purposes of "Server Authentication" and "Client Authentication" but not code-signing.

To get it to be automatically accepted, it needs to be issued by someone like GoDaddy or Verisign.  If you create your own, it will never be automatically accepted until the users manually accept it and place it in their trusted certificate stores.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by creating a certificate myself. Next to 'Choose Certificate' in InfoPath, there is an option for 'Create Certificate' which creates a certficate in your name and then you would be able to select the same when you click on 'Choose Certificate'. Have you tried this option?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, I know this option, but I won't help me, I need a certificate that our users will trust automatically. So it has to be issued by our certification authority and not by me.